# ¿Qué quiere decir “estar de rodríguez"?

Tags: definiciones, expresiones

Colquialmente se dice "estar de rodríguez" al hecho de que un hombre se quede en casa solo mientras su mujer [e hijos] están en otro lugar, normalmente de vacaciones. ¿Es totalmente válida esta explicación? ¿Tiene esta expresión alguna otra acepción?

Leo en [¿De dónde surge la expresión ‘estar de rodríguez’ cuando alguien se queda solo en casa?](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-surge-la-expresion-estar-de-rodriguez/) alguna explicación, pero podría ser interesante tener una explicación canónica (e histórica).

Además, ¿tiene alguna otra connotación en otros países de habla castellana?

Comment: No conocemos (o al menos yo) esa expresión en Colombia. ¿En qué país la usan?

Comment: @DanielEscudero en España. La respuesta de alex lo describe a la perfección, al parecer es solo en ese país.

Comment: Yo he oído usar la expresión no sólo cuando la mujer e hijos se van de vacaciones (que es poco común que vayan sin el padre), sino cuando se van los padres y el hijo (o hijos) se queda(n) solo(s).

Comment: @Diego ¡interesante! Esa variante no la conocía y me parece una evolución lógica y divertida del término. En el artículo que enlacé en mi pregunta se indica que surgió a mediados de los 60, cuando en la España que se industrializaba era típica la visión del padre oficinista y la madre ama de casa que iba a veranear (¿a Benidorm?) con los hijos. Gracias por el apunte.

Comment: Interesante. Acabo de ver en wikipedia que la banda española-argentina Los Rodríguez se llamaban así precisamente por esta expresión.

Comment: @Nicolás ¡qué gracia! (y qué gran grupo). http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Rodr%C3%ADguez#Historia _"El nombre definitivo se debe a que a Calamaro le resultó ingenioso el significado que tiene en España la expresión estar de Rodríguez (expresión que se dice cuando el cabeza de familia tiene que quedarse en la ciudad por cuestiones de trabajo mientras su esposa e hijos disfrutan en la playa), pues él mismo estaba de Rodríguez, ya que había dejado a su novia en Argentina."_

Comment: Mi padre usa esta expresión en una carta que escribió en agosto de 1960

Comment: @user13171 interesantísimo. Esto confirma la hipótesis de que no viene de la película de 1965.

Comment: Esa expresion nunca la habia escuchado, yo creci en Mexico y conozco varios estados de la Republica pero jamas eschuche eso. El que un hombre se quede en casa mientras la esposa e hijos se encuentran en otro lado o de vacaciones... puede dicir muchas cosas, en algun pais en particular. Yo lo pongo en practica muy seguido, so I guess "estoy de Rodriguez?" lol

Answer (score 11, accepted):

La expresión *estar de rodríguez* es totalmente válida. En efecto, según el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/rodr%C3%ADguez), esta locución tiene una única acepción.

> **rodríguez** 
> (De Rodríguez, apellido)
>
> Hombre casado que se queda trabajando mientras su familia está fuera, normalmente de veraneo.

La etimología de esta expresión no es clara, puesto que está sujeta a debate. Existen fuentes que apuntan que esta locución nace de *El cálido verano del Sr. Rodríguez*, una película dirigida por Pedro Lazaga. Sin embargo, otras (*cf*. [ABC](http://abcblogs.abc.es/proxima-estacion/public/post/viajar-estar-de-rodriguez-16571.asp), Fundéu) señalan que esta película fue posterior.

> Es difícil saber el origen de la expresión, **pero con certeza no viene de esta película de 1965**, que probablemente se limitara a sacar partido comercial a una expresión ya usada. Prueba de ello es que podemos encontrar la expresión «estar de Rodríguez» (así escrita) en el libro publicado en 1964, titulado *Panorama español contemporáneo*, por lo que no cabe descartar que se usara desde, como poco, principios de los años 60.

Por último, por lo que he averiguado, esta expresión es utilizada casi exclusivamente en España.

Comment: Fantástica investigación y respuesta, muchas gracias... ¡y bienvenido a la comunidad!