# Origen de la expresión "a todo gas"

Tags: etimología, expresiones, coloquialismos

Las series infantiles siguen siendo un filón de preguntas. En la serie de Blaze, en el doblaje español de España usan la expresión

> dale caña a todo gas

en un momento de la canción de introducción. Fedorqui ya preguntó por el significado de [dar caña](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14915/12637) en otra pregunta, así que me centraré en la segunda parte.

Según [el diccionario](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IyS0m4t#5q7kSdF), la expresión significa "a toda velocidad", pero ¿de dónde proviene la expresión? ¿Cuál y cuándo fue su origen? Más que nada me lo pregunto porque los coches no funcionan con gas, sino con gasolina.

Las alternativas que me planteo son:

- Tiene que ver con la tercera acepción de "gas": "Mezcla de carburante y de aire que alimenta el motor de un vehículo automóvil."
- Es una traducción de alguna expresión inglesa, dado que "gas" en inglés es una forma abreviada de "gasoline".
- Es más antigua de lo que parece y en su origen hacía referencia a un vehículo o aparato que funcionaba a gas.

La primera opción casi podría parecer la opción obvia, pero como nunca se sabe...

Comment: ¿[Peret](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9pQceJpEDo)? :) Dicho esto, _dale caña a todo gas_ parece redundante: yo diría cualquiera de las dos (_dale caña_ y _ve a todo gas_) para indicar lo mismo.

Comment: @fedorqui la serie es para niños de 2 a 5 años, no le puedes pedir mucho... :-)

Comment: Disculpa las ediciones, estoy [deslindando jerga y coloquialismos](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2575/1674) poco a poco, intentando no perturbar demasiado la página inicial.

Comment: @fedorqui edita y perturba tranquilo, no hay problema. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es interesante notar que la segunda acepción de *gas* en 1925 (visto a través del [Mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios)) dice:

> 2. Carburo de hidrógeno con mezcla de otros gases, que se obtiene por la destilación en vasos cerrados del carbón de piedra y **se emplea** para alumbrado o calefacción y **para obtener fuerza motriz**.

Veo que hay expresiones similares en inglés ([véase comparativa en Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=full%20throttle%2Cfull%20steam%2Cwide%20open%20throttle&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfull%20throttle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfull%20steam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwide%20open%20throttle%3B%2Cc0)):

- WOT - *wide-open throttle*
- *full throttle*, muy común en los años 40
- *full steam*, también común en los años 40 y también finales de los años 1910.

En el caso castellano, *a todo gas* [ha ido creciendo](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20todo%20gas&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20todo%20gas%3B%2Cc0) en distintos momentos: finales de los 1960, finales de los 1970 y actualmente se registra su mayor uso desde siempre. Probablemente, su gran uso actual es debido a los libros de cine que hacen referencias a la serie de películas [*Fast & Furious*](http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/movie-group.php?group-id=6), traducida en España como *A todo gas*.

Un momento importante en el uso de la expresión en castellano es el uso en 1969 en una película protagonizada por Peret: [*Amor a todo gas*](http://www.filmaffinity.com/es/film559481.html).
Ver el título de esta película y comparar el gráfico es todo uno para (igual que con [*estar de rodríguez*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12397/1674)) pensar que en los años 60 por algún motivo se popularizó esta expresión. A mi entender, es cuando se popularizó el coche en España y, por tanto, ir rápido con algún vehículo a motor empezó a cobrar sentido. De alguna forma entró esta expresión con fuerza y la película no hizo más que constatar su uso.

Mi hipótesis es que alguien incorporó las expresiones inglesas *full throttle* / *full steam* como *a todo gas* y rápidamente se propagó, utilizando el término *gas* que hacia mediados del siglo XX vimos que el DRAE recogía como elemento usado para obtener fuerza motriz.

Comment: En ingles usamos tambien _step on the gas_. Es una frase norteamericano, en Reino Unido no ponemos gas/gasoline en nuestros coches. En aleman se use _gibt's Gas_ pero alli no se pone gas en sus coches tampoco.

Comment: Opino que es una variante de la saga: *a toda vela* (náutica) y *a toda máquina* (máquina de vapor). Estas han sido las principales fuerzas motrices con las que el hombre ha viajado sobre un sistema de locomoción sin animales. Estaría bien saber si en la edad media decian "a todo caballo" o "a todo burro" :-).

Comment: @Laiv: Estoy de acuerdo. Y no olvidemos _a todo trapo_, que en mi experiencia se usa más que _a toda vela_, aunque sea la misma cosa...

Comment: @rodrigo y la más coloquial... *A toda hostia*... Esa sí que da para abrir una pregunta XD

Comment: @Laiv Lo decía porque trapo es sinónimo de vela. Hostia no es más que una variante blasfema... y en español eso se puede hacer con casi cualquier expresión... somos así de imaginativos!