# ¿Cómo traducir "staycation" al español?

Tags: traducción, modismos, solicitud-de-término

`Staycation` es un modismo anglosajón que combina "stay" (quedarse) y "vacation" (vacaciones). A veces también se usa `holystay` que combina "holydays" (días festivos como Navidad o Pascua) y "stay".

Así que `staycation` se usa para decir, "He estado de vacaciones, pero en lugar de irme de viaje me he quedado donde vivo". Cuando uno está de "staycation" (o "holystay", si resultan ser las vacaciones de Navidad o Pascua o similar y no "*vuelves a casa por navidad*" como en aquel memorable anuncio del turrón) hace viajes de ida y vuelta en el día (vuelve a casa para dormir), visita los museos locales, quizá queda con los amigos de siempre ...

En español tenemos algunos modismos relacionados con las vacaciones, como "[estar de rodrigez](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12397/5481)", pero no me viene a la cabeza nada que implique "estoy de vacaciones, disfrutando aquí donde vivo en lugar de ir de viaje".

¿Hay un modismo o término en español que se use para lo mismo que "staycation/holystay"?

Comment: Qué facilidad tienen los anglosajones para sacar términos de cada cosa :) Veo que por aquí a veces le llaman [_quedación_](http://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/staycation.html).

Comment: Así a bote pronto se me ocurre "vacaciones caseras".

Comment: I thonk staycation actually means staying in your own country instead of going abroad for your holiday not staying in your own home.

Comment: @mdewey I disagree, because I hear it in the United States. People in the USA might go to a different state for vacation or holidays.That trip can range from a 2 hour drive, an 8 hour drive or longer, or a train ride or flight.  They use the term as "I didn't travel" not as "I didn't travel **abroad**". That should be the case for other languages/countries. If you live in Madrid but you go to Barcelona in the AVE it is not a "staycation" even if you went back to Madrid at the end of the day. If you take a day trip to the mountains it is (travel, but not far).

Comment: If you want to translate it into Spanish you would need to know which country the original speaker came from. If it was from the UK it has the meaning I suggest. Perhaps I should have included my dialect information in my answer so apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @mdewey I see your point, because in UK is easier to travel abroad, especially through other European countries. Nevertheless, it is the opposite in the States, but bot use the term (see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staycation). Also, I'm not just looking for a "direct translation". A idiom (a la "estar de rodrigez" for example) would be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Uno de los significados de la palabra **vacation** es precisamente viajar o pasar un *tiempo lejos de casa*. A pesar de que en inglés, otro significado es el de *un intervalo de tiempo durante el cual no se trabaja*; parece ser que es común en inglés asociar la palabra **vacation** en el sentido de estar lejos de casa.

En español, la palabra **vacación** no tiene ninguna acepción en la cual sea sinónimo de viaje o *estar lejos de casa*. **Vacaciones** significa simplemente, el intervalo de tiempo durante el cual no se trabaja o estudia. Se pueden hacer muchas cosas durante este intervalo además de viajar.

> - ¿Qué harás en las vacaciones?
>   - ¿Yo?... Estudiaré. ¿Y tú?
>   - ¡Ah! Yo iré a Sudamérica

Por lo tanto, las fórmulas similares a **vacaciones en casa** o **vacaciones caseras** son correctas.

---

Sin embargo, en español también existe el término **vacacionar** cuyo significado siempre tiene adherido el sentido de viajar. No es necesario, en mi opinión, que el viaje sea largo aunque si que sea fuera del lugar de residencia. Tampoco es necesario que se trasnoche en el lugar alterno.

A mi parecer, el término **staycation** utiliza el recurso de la retórica para unir dos términos opuestos y hacer énfasis en el hecho de que uno se quedará en casa.

Si queremos aplicar el sentido irónico de la frase en inglés podríamos decir también **vacacionar en casa** o **vacacionar en la ciudad**:

> - Krauss, ¿A dónde irás de vacaciones?
>   - Voy a vacacionar en Tijuana
>   - ¡Hombre! Al menos tienes que ir a Tecate