# ¿Existe una versión femenina para la expresión "estar de rodríguez"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, españa, solicitud-de-modismo

La definición de la expresión *estar de rodríguez*, ya [tratada aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12397/12637) y usada solo en España, es [la siguiente](https://dle.rae.es/rodr%C3%ADguez):

> 1. m. coloq. Hombre casado que se queda trabajando mientras su familia está fuera, normalmente de veraneo.

Me llama la atención que la expresión se recoja como solo usada en el caso de que la persona que se queda trabajando sea un hombre. Entiendo que la definición se basa en el uso que las personas hacen de la propia expresión, dado que la RAE es una simple notaria de dicho uso.

Sin embargo, veo totalmente natural que la expresión se use también cuando la persona que se queda en casa no es un hombre. Pregunto pues:

- ¿Se registra en el uso actual del español la misma expresión usada en el caso de no ser un hombre quien se queda en casa mientras la familia está fuera?
- Si no es así, ¿existe alguna expresión alternativa para dichos casos?

Answer (score 2):

El hecho de que los "rodríguez" sean tradicionalmente hombres refleja la situación habitual en España en los años 60, cuando se le dio nombre.

Pero eso no impide usarlo para referirse a mujeres (es un apellido, y no cambia el género como ocurre en ruso). Yo lo he oído así alguna vez y [hay quien dice](https://blogdeespanol.com/2015/08/estar-de-rodriguez/) que es habitual.

Comment: Yo también he oído a mujeres decir que están de Rodríguez.